# CRC error when extracting to SSD from 2nd HDD

Tags: ssd, compression, crc

I have a large RAR file (split up) containing an ISO on my 2nd HDD

When I extract it:

- to the same HDD, it's OK
- to the system/OS SSD, I get CRC errors

I've checked memory, run memtests, checked wires etc

I have no other issues; only with this one RAR file with both 7-zip and WinACE

Any ideas please?

Comment: in trying to troubleshoot this kind of issue, i would extract to both devices (forcefully if necessary; some archivers delete the extracted file on error), then do a bitwise comparison of the extracted files.  (i'd compare MD5 or SHA hashes; there are other methods that also work.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forgot about this... after investigation, my motherboard south bridge did not support AHCI.

I changed board (and CPU etc: any excuse for new toys) and problem solved.